# PyMySQL.connect() Ignoring Password

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am having a trouble in python 3.6 accessing a Mysql Database using PyMySQL (version 0.8.0 ) :

```
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect("localhost","user","password","database")
```

However I get the error:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Why does it say USING PASSWORD: NO ? It seems like it is ignoring the password - any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that's the connect line triggering the error? Does that work in isolation from your main app?

Comment: yes even if I go into the python console and just try typing those commands in the console I still get the same error. And it also states in the error message that the db = pymysql...... line triggers the error

Answer (score 1):

The pymysql you use does not support mysql 8.0 or later. I attach the issue of github together and recommend to downgrade to 5.xx virgin after confirmation.

https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/651